# SBJson and NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata, sbjson

I'm getting data from quizlet.com and it works OK for simple code:

```
-(void) grabbQuizletWithUrl:(NSURL*)requstURL {

     NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:requestURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; 

     NSDictionary *dict = [dataString JSONValue];
}
```

But I need to use NSURLConnection to start and stop activity indicator. I'm trying

```
-(void) grabbQuizletWithUrl:(NSURL*)requstURL {

    NSURLRequest *quizletRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestURL];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:quizletRequest
                                                          delegate:self];
    [connection release];
    [quizletRequest release];

}

// and getting data in delegate method:



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *dict = [dataString JSONValue];

}
```

I'm getting messages like these:

[2377:707] -JSONValue failed. Error is: Unexpected end of input

[2377:707] -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [.]

[2377:707] -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [d]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;`, you should just append the recieved data to the previously stored, as you only got just a part of the response, ie :

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // someNSMutableDataIVar is an ivar to store the data in
    [someNSMutableDataIVar appendData:data];
}
```

then in another delegate method called :`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;` you should process the data.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // the connection finished loading all data, process...
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] 
                            initWithData:someNSMutableDataIVar
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dict = [dataString JSONValue];
}
```

The asynchronous URL loading system is described in detail in the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA) from Apple.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you, that's what I missed! Now it works. I did not learn that Apple's guide but just glanced over it.